# How to add multiple values in SQL using comma operator

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
alter Procedure sp_range_chkbox       
    @Price int,        
    @Price1 int,      
    @chkValue varchar(max)  
as        
begin        
    IF (@chkValue > 0)        
    begin        
        select 
            ProductID, ProductName, ProductImage, ProductPrice 
        from 
            tblProddetails 
        where 
           (ProductPrice between @Price and @Price1) 
           and (CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(Categoryid as VARCHAR(8000)) + ',', ',' + @chkvalue + ',') > 0)    
    end        
    else        
    begin        
        select 
            ProductID, ProductName, ProductImage, ProductPrice 
        from  
            tblProddetails 
        where 
            ProductPrice between @Price and @Price1          
    end        
end
```

Here I am using `@chkvalue` as `Varchar(max)`

But the code throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3,1' to data type int

Comment: I think you want to check if the `LEN(@chkValue) > 0`

Comment: @WEI_DBA  (LEN(@chkValue) > 0) hbow to use this in the If Condtion

Comment: In the If statement, replace `@chkValue` with `LEN(@chkValue)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `IF (@chkValue > 0)`  to `IF(LEN(@chkValue)>0)`

```
alter Procedure sp_range_chkbox       
    @Price int,        
    @Price1 int,      
    @chkValue varchar(max)  
as        
begin        
    IF(LEN(@chkValue)>0)       
    begin        
        select 
            ProductID, ProductName, ProductImage, ProductPrice 
        from 
            tblProddetails 
        where 
           (ProductPrice between @Price and @Price1) 
           and (CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(Categoryid as VARCHAR(8000)) + ',', ',' + @chkvalue + ',') > 0)    
    end        
    else        
    begin        
        select 
            ProductID, ProductName, ProductImage, ProductPrice 
        from  
            tblProddetails 
        where 
            ProductPrice between @Price and @Price1          
    end        
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This check is the problem..

```
IF (@chkValue > 0)
```

For obvious reasons, SQL server tries to convert `@chkValue` to integer, which originally is of type `varchar(max)`. Value you passed to `@chkValue`, which must be  `'3,1'` by looking at your error message, is failing to be converted to Integer.